# Passing json text to api

Tags: arrays, json, api, postman

```js
{
    "data": {
        "id": 41
    },
    "payments": {
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "invoice_id": 41,
                "amount": 12,
                "account": {
                    "data": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "company_id": 1,
                        "name": "Cash",
                        "current_balance": 12,
                        "bank_name": "Cash"
                    }
                },
                "currency": {
                    "data": {
                        "id": 5,
                        "company_id": 1,
                        "code": "USD",
                        "precision": "2",
                        "symbol": "$"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Postman gives this json file for GET request. How can I pass this as json text to an API? When I pass same data displayed here it won't work. In payments section there is an array for "data", What should be the format to pass a json text in this case?

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify()`

Answer (score 0):

Choose POST method. Click on body tab. There will be option raw , paste the JSON there and hit send.

Comment: I want to pass the json text from my web page. (i'm using php cURL)

Comment: $.ajax({ type : "POST", url : "/apiUrl" , data : { info : "your json text" } }).done(function(){ });

Comment: In short make an ajax call from JS of your page. @BinodMadhubashitha . You will need the jquery library.

Comment: If it's still not resolved. Please share your repo or code here. I'll have a look.

Comment: Passing method is working. But is there a format to enter data? I set $data variable like this --> $data='{"data":{"id":2}}'

Comment: $data='{\"data\":{\"id\":2}}' try this. If you are making JSON using string make sure to use escape \ to skip " quotes inside.